# C++ Reference Variable

Tags: c++

How to use 'reference variables' in C++ classes?

I have the following code that I want to put into a class: (note KinectCV&)

```
KinectCV& kinect = freenect.createDevice(0);
kinect.some_init_functions();
while(condition) {
    // getting frames from kinect and processing
    kinect.some_processing_functions();
}
kinect.some_stopping_functions();
```

I'm trying to make a class and separate init, process and stop functions:

```
class MyKinect {
    public:
    KinectCV kinect;
    void init(){
        /* I cannot use the '& kinect = freenect.createDevice(0);' syntax, help me in this */
    }
    void process(){
        kinect.some_processing_functions();
    }
    void stop(){
        kinect.some_stopping_functions();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want kinect to be a reference, you'll have to assign it in MyKinect's constructor

Comment: _'I cannot use the '& kinect = freenect.createDevice(0);' syntax'_ What's the exact error you're getting with this?

Comment: Do you have a reason for having an "init" function instead using the class's constructor? As already said, you have to initialize your references in your constructor, they're not allowed to not refer to anything while the class is live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot use the '& kinect = freenect.createDevice(0)

That is right, you cannot *assign* references; once initialized, they refer to the same object forever. What looks like an assignment in your code that works

```
KinectCV& kinect = freenect.createDevice(0);
```

is not an assignment, it's initialization. It can be rewritten using the initialization syntax instead of the assignment syntax, like this:

```
KinectCV& kinect(freenect.createDevice(0));
```

The reason behind it is that in C++ all initialization must happen in the constructor, not in a "designated initialization function". C++ has no idea that `init` is your initialization function; all it knows is that once the constructor is over, the object must be in a consistent state, included with all the references that it might hold.

Moving the initialization code into `MyKinect`'s constructor will fix the problem:

```
class MyKinect {
    public:
    KinectCV kinect;
    MyKinect() : kinect(freenect.createDevice(0)) {
    }
}
```